# How to take some commits from a branch and merge those commit with another branch in git

Tags: git, branch

Ok i have the following situation. I have a branch which is called **develop**.
From develop i created a branch which is called **AIOEC-393**.
It contains the following commits:

> nicoladj77    Reinstalling wordpress   938f469
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-122: Added feeds for ai1ec_events  2254569
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-122: removed parsed css file   d10e29e
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-122: added comment to function     38054dd
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-393: Starting to move files    6f92360
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-393 moved classes and took out require_once calls 
>   b7ab691
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-393: starting to move base container   87e8b91
>
> nicoladj77    AIOEC-393: moved classes as suggested and refactored a
>   little while i… …  1093032

I need to create another branch which is based on **develop** and contains only the last four commits of **AIOEC-393** ( of course the commits that start with AIOEC-393 ). How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git cherry-pick` can do this. Just give the commit ID you want to merge into your current branch as argument to the command. This will "cherry pick" the commit, even if the commit belongs to a different branch.

Or, what also should work is:

1. Clone/checkout the branch
2. Rewind a number of commits (reset --hard commit_ID)
3. Cherry-pick the commits you want

This avoids doing a rebase.

Comment: No i just want to make a new branch which is "develop" + the latest four commits

Comment: `reset --hard` is dangerous advice …

Answer (score 1):

If the commits are the first commits on your branch, you can simply checkout the last commit and create a new branch at its place:

```
git checkout -b new_branch <id of "AIOEC-393: Starting to move files 6f92360">
```

If there are other commits (you don't want) before the commits you want in the new branch, create a new branch and rebase it:

```
git checkout -b new_branch <last commit you want>
git rebase --onto develop <commit before your commits> new_branch
```

Alternatively, create a branch off `develop` and cherry pick the commits you want:

```
git checkout -b new_branch develop
git cherry-pick <commit before your commits>..<last commit you want>
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose you a solution with `rebase onto`. Say we have the following repo :

```
user@HOST c:/_TEMP/FOO (AIOEC-393) $ git lga
* 8c2d5c5 - (HEAD, AIOEC-393) commit5 (Yanflea 2 minutes  ago)
* 3c20e52 - commit4 (Yanflea 2 minutes  ago)
* c5383af - commit3 (Yanflea 2 minutes  ago)
* fb11e98 - commit2 (Yanflea 2 minutes  ago)
* e019261 - (develop) commit1 (Yanflea 2 minutes  ago)
* 0cfe064 - (master) Initial commit (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
```

And you want to have all commits from `AIOEC-393` branch except *commit2*.

Let's move to a 'temp' branch (so that `AIOEC-393` is not modified):

```
$ git checkout -b develop-target
```

and then use the `rebase onto` command using *commit2* as pivot :

```
$ git rebase --onto develop fb11e98 develop-target
```

Let's see the log :

```
user@HOST c:/_TEMP/FOO (develop-target) $ git lga
* 7bcb162 - (HEAD, develop-target) commit5 (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
* 3c89459 - commit4 (Yanflea  2 minutes ago)
* e6ed5f7 - commit3 (Yanflea  2 minutes ago)
* e019261 - (develop) commit1 (Yanflea  2 minutes ago)
* 0cfe064 - (master) Initial commit (Yanflea  2 minutes ago)
```

Now we just have to fast-forward from `develop` to `develop-target` (and then remove `develop-target`):

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git rebase develop-target
$ git branch -d develop-target
```

The log :

```
user@HOST c:/_TEMP/FOO (develop) $ git lga
* 7bcb162 - (HEAD, develop) commit5 (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
* 3c89459 - commit4 (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
* e6ed5f7 - commit3 (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
* e019261 - commit1 (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
* 0cfe064 - (master) Initial commit (Yanflea 2 minutes ago)
```